# Закрытие элемента из вне jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Не много увлёкся вёрсткой 
Первую свою реализацию как для примера взял верхнюю панель Stack Overflow!

Получилось добиться только открытия `input` и скрытие меню.

```js
$(".js-input").on("click", function() {
  $(".js-ul").addClass("opacity");
  $(this).addClass("nw");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.items {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
  width: auto;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.nw {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}

li {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items flex">
  <div class="item flex">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://d15shllkswkct0.cloudfront.net/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2011/09/lenovo-logo.gif" alt="">
    </div>
    <ul class="js-ul flex">
      <li><a href="">Activity</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tags</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <form action="">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск" class="js-input">
  </form>
</div>
```

Это также видно на so при клике в поле поиска.
Подскажите, как теперь закрыть search вне этого элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Но я всё равно **по-своему** придумал решение:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fixed").on("click", function() {
    $(".js-input").removeClass("nw");
    $(".js-ul").removeClass("opacity");
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $(".js-input").on("click", function() {
    $(".js-ul").addClass("opacity");
    $(this).addClass("nw");
    $(".fixed").show();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.items {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .4s linear;
  width: auto;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.nw {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}

li {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.js-input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items flex">
  <div class="item flex">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://d15shllkswkct0.cloudfront.net/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2011/09/lenovo-logo.gif" alt="">
    </div>
    <ul class="js-ul flex">
      <li><a href="">Activity</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Users</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tags</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <form action="">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск" class="js-input">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

Comment: я когда то так же делал .. почти всегда

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дали на toster.ru и он такой :

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".js-input");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.removeClass('nw');
        $(".js-ul").removeClass("opacity");
    }
});
```